# Broken apt-get upgrade

Tags: apt, upgrade

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 and attempting a apt-get upgrade which is currently failing with the below error. I am alittle bit stuck.

```
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.103ubuntu4.2) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-30-generic
cp: cannot stat ‘/lib/libnss_nisplus-2.19.31a.so’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/lib/libnss_nisplus-2.19.31a.so’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/lib/libnss_nisplus-2.19.31a.so’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/lib/libnss_nisplus-2.19.31a.so’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/lib/libnss_nisplus-2.19.31a.so’: No such file or directory
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/fixrtc failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-30-generic with 1.
dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 initramfs-tools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Anything that I attempt to run now with apt-get fails.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you should do if you ran in such probs, is: 
open a terminal and type `dpkg --audit`, and, depending on what `dpkg` returns, you could continue with the following steps.

---

From the command line:

`sudo apt --fix-missing install`

`sudo apt --fix-broken install`

`sudo apt autoremove`

`sudo apt autoclean`

`sudo apt clean`

`sudo apt update`

`sudo apt upgrade`

Make sure to check out, what `apt` is proposing as solution after every step.